# Gradle: How to run Sonar on a separate process/JVM

Tags: java, groovy, gradle, jvm, sonarqube

I found that there is an open issue to make easy to run Sonar on a separate process (similar to compile task):

http://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-2587

But I was wondering if there is some workaround while this is implemented.

Is there any easy way to run an specific Gradle task in a separate process using a different JVM?

I am new to Gradle and I have a build that needs to run in IBM JDK, which is not supported by Sonar, so I need to switch to Oracle JDK only for Sonar runner task, and probably also configure some extra memory for this process, since Sonar needs a lot of memory.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, a contribution for this is underway (and perhaps it will make it into Gradle 2.1). Until then, if you must run Sonar in a separate process, the only solution is to use the standalone Sonar runner (see Sonar docs).